# Javascript SetInterval not waiting properly?

Tags: javascript

In my javascript I have:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    setInterval(test('test alert'), 10000);
});

function test(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```

Simple, when the document is ready, it should set up the setInterval... Which basically means, wait 10 seconds, run the function, then repeat every 10 seconds.

The problem is the setInterval is not activating properly. The test function is being fired immediately (instead of waiting 10 seconds), and never fires again subsequent times. What am I doing wrong here?

Now, if I set up my setInterval as follows, it works fine... but why?

```
setInterval(function() { test('test alert'); }, 10000);
```

Comment: Your code is working please check `http://jsfiddle.net/kw3Mm/` i think you are using wrong place your code

Comment: Also do not use alert in interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're passing the *return value* of *invoking the function*, not the function itself.  What you want is this:

```
setInterval(test, 10000);
```

If you need to pass an argument into the test, you have to wrap it in another function:

```
setInterval(function(){test('test alert');}, 10000);
```

Whenever you use a literal followed by parenthesis (like `test()` or `test('test alert')`, the parentheses are a signal to JavaScript to *invoke the function*.  To test this for yourself, try the following in an interactive console in your browser:

```
console.log('test: ' + test);
console.log('test(): ' + test());
```

The first will tell you that the value is a *function*; the second will tell you `undefined`; that's because the function (`test`) has been invoked, and the value returned.

Note that in JavaScript, functions are first-class citizens, so there's nothing wrong with creating a function that itself returns a function:

```
function test(value) {
    return function(){
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

If you did that, your `setInterval` would work as you originally expected it to:

```
// test('test alert') returns a function
setInterval(test('test alert'), 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)** expects a *function* or an *`eval()`-able string* as its first argument. In your code, you are passing it the return value of the function `test()`

Instead it should be:

```
setInterval(function() {
    test('test alert');
}, 10000);
```